# parsing json with swiftyJson swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, swifty-json

Dummy question: 
I have my json:

```
       let jsonDestination = "[{\"data\": {\"destinos\": [{\"idDestino\": \"1\",\"desDestino\": \"ASUNCION\"},{\"idDestino\": \"2\",\"desDestino\": \"MIAMI\"}]}}]"
```

And try to print the result if "idDestino" like this:

```
    if let dataFromString = jsonDestination.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let destinationJson = JSON(data: dataFromString)

        for item in destinationJson["destinos"].arrayValue {
            print(item["idDestino"].stringValue)
        }
    }
```

But, never enter to execute the line `print(item["idDestino"].stringValue)`

Also i try this:

```
let firtsDestinationId = destinationJson[0]["data"]["destinos"]["idDestino"]
print(firtsDestinationId)
```

and get this error:

> _error    NSError?    domain: "SwiftyJSONErrorDomain" - code: 901 0x000060000005c080
>   This error is means: Couldn't merge, because the JSONs differ in type on top level

Same for: `let firtsDestinationId = destinationJson["data"][0]["destinos"]["idDestino"]`

So..my real problem is i don't know how to catch the data of my json... can any help me here?

PD.: this example work just fine:

```
let jsonDestination =  "{ \"people\": [{ \"firstName\": \"Paul\", \"lastName\": \"Hudson\", \"isAlive\": true }, { \"firstName\": \"Angela\", \"lastName\": \"Merkel\", \"isAlive\": true }, { \"firstName\": \"George\", \"lastName\": \"Washington\", \"isAlive\": false } ] }"

          if let dataFromString = jsonDestination.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let destinationJson = JSON(data: dataFromString)

        for item in destinationJson["people"].arrayValue {
            print(item["firstName"].stringValue)
        }
    }
```

My json is the problem? how to can use correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my comments for each level in your JSON object

```
[-----------------------------------------Array
   {--------------------------------------Obj
      "data":{----------------------------Obj
         "destinos":[---------------------Array
            {-----------------------------Obj
               "idDestino":"1",
               "desDestino":"ASUNCION"
            },
            {  
               "idDestino":"2",
               "desDestino":"MIAMI"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Your code below doesn't work because JSON element for destinos is an array.

```
let firtsDestinationId = destinationJson[0]["data"]["destinos"]["idDestino"]
```

You cant try this following code

```
let firtsDestinationId = destinationJson[0]["data"]["destinos"][0]["idDestino"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who want to go through the Json[array]... in my case i write this code:

```
       for item in destinationJson["data"]["destinos"].arrayValue {
            print(item["idDestino"].stringValue)
        }
```